# Sensitivity of a diagnostic test

Tags: probability, bayesian, sensitivity-specificity

Diagnostic tests A1 and A2 are used to detect the presence or absence of a disease. The results of A1 and A2 are a priori independent of the presence or absence of the disease.
A1 and A2 have sensitivity Sen1 and Sen2, respectively. A new diagnostic test T is introduced. T is positive when A1 and A2 are both positive. Determine the sensitivity of T.

Initially, I thought I would use Bayes theorem, as it contains sensitivity and re-arranging the equation I would get the sensitvity of T:
P(Test+│D)=P(D│Test+)*(P(test+│D)*P(D)+P(test+│notD)*P(notD))/P(D)

But since there are no numbers behind, I don´t know how to solve this problem..

any help is highly appreciated!